# Internet access in Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

Actually i am unable to access internet in android emulator. when i am trying to open website in webview, in emulator it is not loading. i tried using inbuilt webkit browser also in emulator but facing the same problem, it is not loading. When i executed the same project last 15 days back it was executed successful but now it was not loading.
can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: Describe your problem in more detail.

Comment: if i am opening any website in emulator means it is not loading i mean i can see url loading on screen but i website is not loading. after some time getting as connection timed out & it was closing in emulator....

Comment: What is your IDE? Are you connected through a proxy?

Comment: i am using Eclipse Indigo.. i don't have any idea regarding connection through proxy.. can you plz explain it...

Comment: Check your firewalls settings and try to disable your LAN card.

Comment: Go to the `network connections`, find your LAN card, right click it and choose `disable`. If you use wireless on Windows 7 close the emulator, disable your LAN card and start the emulator again.

Comment: still it is not connecting in emulator.... just loading url is only displaying.........

Comment: It has got to be a proxy issue.

Comment: In this case correctly configure proxy.

Comment: Also try by pressing F8 key when you have focus on emulator

Comment: solved the problem. in network connections if i am using public network means everything is working correctly, but if i am using home network means getting problem. i changed my network from home to public network. now the website is loading. thanks for your suggestions.........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're behind a proxy you must correctly configure proxy settings of your emulator. The easiest way is to do the following (this's for Android Emulator 4.0.3):

1. go to `Menu`
2. click on `Settings`
3. click `More` in `Wireless and Networks`
4. click `Mobile Networks`
5. click `Access Point Names`
6. click `TelKila` Internet
7. enter `Proxy` and `Port`
8. enter `Username` and `Password` if required and rest of the fields leave them blank
9. press `Save`